# Changing domain, can't connect

Tags: sql-server, configuration, windows-server, connectivity, service-accounts

I have a server that hosts a SQL Server 2017 Entreprise Edition database. I changed domain on the server (e.g. attds.mg in fdsqq.mg).

The problem is that I can't connect my application to the database. The account I used as a SA administrator for SQL Server does not even work.

I checked the SQL Server Configuration Manager, all services were stopped. So I can't connect to my DB.

Would someone have a solution to reactivate the services? How could I connect to the database?

Comment: I believe the service account for SQL Server is using old domain account which is no longer valid, hence failing. You can change the service account of SQL Server to NT Authority\System and see if it starts. Later please change it to the new domain service account.

Comment: yes guys thank you it works !!!! kiss @Shanky